# Bash formatting 80 line on user input

Tags: bash

I was wondering if it was possible to make sure if description or srcofhlp was over 80 line of text, that it would wrap and go to the next line and create a `*` in the same format. I was looking into fold but didn't know if it was possible to reformat so a newline with a `*` would show.
So example:

```
/*
 * Filename: BOB
 * Author: Whatever
 * Description: Hi lets just pretend this is over 80 character
 *              and let this continue like this
 */
```

-

```
printf "Enter the author: " ; read -r author
printf "Enter the UserID: " ; read -r usrid
printf "Enter the description: " ; read -r description 
printf "Enter sources of help: " ; read -r srcofhlp

printf "%-16s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%-16s%-8s\n\
%s\n\n\n" '/*' ' * Filename: ' "$filename" ' * Author: ' \
"$author" ' * UserId: ' "$usrid" ' * Description: ' "${description} " ' * Date: ' \
"$today" ' * Sources of Help: ' "$srcofhlp" ' */' > $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little function that might help - or at least point you in the right direction:

```
#!/bin/bash

author='whatever'
description='Hello lets just pretend this is over 80 character and let this continue like this blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah fdjsklf fsdf a f dsg a g asg sg g asgd a sdg sggsag   g asdg sa g s gd sag  '

function format_description() {
    local start

    fmt -w 60 <<< "$description" | while read line
    do
        if ! ((start++))
        then
            echo " * Description: $line"
        else
            echo " *              $line"
        fi
    done
}

format_description "$description"
```

This outputs:

```
 * Description: Hello lets just pretend this is over 80 character and let
 *              this continue like this blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 *              blah fdjsklf fsdf a f dsg a g asg sg g asgd a sdg sggsag
 *              g asdg sa g s gd sag
```

Comment: What happened to the /* at the beginning and end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way - it doesn't grok the full syntax for C-style comments (i.e. not the beginning `/*` and ending `*/`), but it might be useful:

```
$ echo " * this is a somewhat longish string with a prefix" | fmt -10 -p " * "
 * this
 * is a
 * somewhat
 * longish
 * string
 * with a
 * prefix
$
```